# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str' - Cant seem to convert list

Tags: python, string, types, int, typeerror

So I have written a function which reads a file (csv) and returns the average of each line of numbers, as a list.
I believe the code should work however I have tried many ways and cant get the data to convert to numerical values(that can then be summed etc.) from a list.

```
def line_averages(filename):
    file = open(filename, 'r')
    data = file.readlines()
    file.close()
    x = []
    for i in data:
        data_splitted = i.split()
        line_average = sum(data_splitted) / len(data_splitted)
        x.append(line_average)
    return x
```

specifically when I run this with my file I get:

```
    <class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-100-426fb6997e94>", line 1, in <module>
    line_averagesTEST(e)

  File "C:/Users/liver/Documents/Python Practise/lab4.py", line 32, in line_averagesTEST
    line_average = sum(split) / len(split)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

sorry if an easy fix as I am new to this lol

Comment: Pretty sure you should be getting `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'`

Comment: and/or you've not posted all of your code. Please [edit] your post to include the entire error, including stack trace.

Comment: `float(data_splitted)` is obviously wrong..

Comment: Yes sorry the float() was incorrect. Edited to what I had to get the error now. Thanks.

Comment: `float(data_splitted)` does not convert all elements to floats. Use e.g. `map(float,data_splitted)` instead.

Comment: `sum(data_splitted)` is obviously wrong ;-)  -- hint what is the type of the items in `data_splitted`?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  Your posted code simply defines a function and quits without executing anything.

Comment: Use quick list comprehension to turn your string elements within your data_splitted into integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it looks live you've realized the source of your error is that your `list` contains strings instead of a numeric data type, which is why addition won't work. The naive way to do this (a perfectly reasonable one I might add), is to simply loop:

```
>>> total = 0
>>> for x in split:
...     total += float(x)
...
>>> total
17.0
```

OK, we didn't use the `sum` function. Would *could* also do something like:

```
>>> split_f = []
>>> for x in split:
...     split_f.append(float(x))
...
>>> sum(split_f)
17.0
```

This also works fine, although, it creates an unecessary intermediate list. But note the pattern from the above two loops: you apply the same function over-and-over to each element in the list, i.e. you *map the function onto the list*. Well, Python is batteries included:

```
>>> sum(map(float, split))
17.0
```

Note, on Python3, the above solution doesn't create an unecessary intermediate list!

Answer (score 0):

How is your data in the file arrange? I think you should use the delimiter as an argument in your split function. For instance if you file contains lines like:

> 1,2,3,4...

you must use i.split(",").
When data is split correctly you could use numpy and a notation like that to easily calculate the average
`line_average = np.mean([float(a) for a in data_splitted])`
and you have to put

```
import numpy as np
```

at the beginning of your function.

Answer (score 0):

You read in string data, split it into sub-strings, and then try to sum the strings.  You have to convert the input to numeric types before you can add them.